# seta do slide não esta aparecendo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

eu estou com um problema, eu peguei um codigo de uma video aula e um jquery tambem, estou usando os dois, coloquei os codigos exatamente como estavam no video, mas mesmo assim a minha seta não aparece, fica tipo que um A nela, eu coloquei uma imagem para melhorar a visualização, como eu poderia proceder? o caminho do jquery ta todo certo, do java também, tudo nas pastas certinho e ja foi revisado mais de uma vez, agradeço quem puder me ajudar, abraço.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOezn.png

**Meu código html do slide:**

```
h1 class="inicial"Adicionados Recentemente /h1 div class="carousel"
      div a href="#" img class="slide" src="img/01.png" alt="js" / /div /a
      div a href="#" img src="img/02.png" alt="java" / /div> /a
```

**Codigo do javascript:**

```
script
$('.carousel').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
});
/script
```

**Código CSS:**

```
/* Slider */
.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}    
.slick-list
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;

    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;

    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;

    height: auto;

    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o código de onde está aparecendo esse A.

Comment: Aquilo ali ou é pq fou usada alguma Font especial tipo FontAwesome ou algo do tipo que vc não indexou no css e não colocou na pasta, ou então é pq usaram um código de caractere Unicode e vc colocou o Hexadecimal alguma coisa assim... Mas coloca seu código ai pelo menos o HTML/CSS

Comment: Usar "Java" para se referir a "JavaScript" é a mesma coisa que usar "cachorro" para se referir a "cachorro-quente". São duas coisas completamente diferentes!

Comment: O código ficou todo errado.

Comment: Consegue replicar na aplicação jsfiddle. Será mais facil ajudar.

Comment: Jhonatan, pelo que percebi, você está invertendo o fechamento da "div" e do "a". Está sendo aberto a "div", depois o "a", mas ao fechar, está sendo fechado primeiro a "div" e depois o "a", onde deveria ser o inverso. <div><a>...</a></div>. O seu está ficando assim: <div><a>...</div></a>. Pode ser que isso esteja atrapalhando alguma coisa.